# how to avoid automatic Tabulator header wrap

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I encounter a weird situation...

When the container width less than 100%, the columns always wrap like this:
[set layout as fitColumns, without width specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIHZV.png) The code is:

```
const tbTB=new Tabulator('#stbTB',{
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns:[
        {title:'SPLT',field: 'SPLT', editor:'input',validator:'numeric',headerSort:false},
        {title:'RRH',field: 'RRH', editor:'input',validator:'numeric',headerSort:false},
        {title:'Yaw',field: 'Yaw', editor:'input',validator:'numeric',headerSort:false},
        {title:'Roll',field: 'Roll',editor:'input',validator:'numeric',headerSort:false}
    ]
})
```

If I set layout to fitData, the rows will automatically fill horizontally:
[set layout as fitData, row will fill horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnaU7.png). The code is:

```
const tbTB=new Tabulator('#stbTB',{
    layout: "fitData",
    columns:[
        {title:'SPLT',field: 'SPLT', editor:'input',validator:'numeric',headerSort:false},
        {title:'RRH',field: 'RRH', editor:'input',validator:'numeric',headerSort:false},
        {title:'Yaw',field: 'Yaw', editor:'input',validator:'numeric',headerSort:false},
        {title:'Roll',field: 'Roll',editor:'input',validator:'numeric',headerSort:false}
    ]
})
```

I don't know why does it happen. I copy the simple version to pencode and cannot reproduce this bug. It's a big project that I cannot paste all the code here. I attach the css of container as reference if needed.
[css for the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amLA4.png). The code for creating the container:

```
divSub.append('div')
    .attr('id','stbTB')
    .style('width','49%')
    .style('height','100%');
```

By the way, I have several tables in this page with same settings. If the container width is 100%, it looks good without any unexpected wrap. Does anyone meet similar situation? And how can I fix it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show code here. We can't debug images.

Comment: Also revise your title to ask an actual question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggest that you have some generic CSS sitting somewhere on your site that is interfering with how Tabulator lays out it elements.

Check that you don't have any CSS selectors that are targeting `div` or `*` as these may also interact with Tabulator elements in unexpected ways

Comment: I did check the css setting but all I've done is just setting 'position', 'float', and 'box-sizing' as the screenshot attached. That's why I think it's weird...

Comment: Position float will definitely break the table if it is on any of the tables elements.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just need to figure out which css setting affect this layout. I applied float on all children div of the table's parent node. That's why I got this weird result. Thank you again!